# Naming php files stored in xampp for quick access

Tags: php, xampp

I'm just wondering if it is possible to give a sort of nickname to my php files which I'm using through Xampp so that instead of typing 'localhost/website/index.php' - I would just type in something like 'index.mysite'?

I'm aware it is possible to change the local host name which is something I have already done so now I actually type, 2015/website.index.php but I cant find anywhere to change the rest.

Can anyone be of some knowledge in this area?

Thanks

Comment: Check this : http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-edit-host-file-in-windows-8-1-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the Apache VHost file and also your own systems' hosts file.

So for example say you have a project set up at `C://xampp/htdocs/project_x` in your Apache VHost file (located at `C://xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`) you want to add code similar to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project_x.local
    DocumentRoot "C://xampp/htdocs/project_x"

    <Directory "C://xampp/htdocs/project_x">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Next (if you're on a Windows OS) you will need to change your system's host file. This file is located at `C://Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`. You will need to copy and paste this file somewhere where you can edit it, such as your desktop. You can then add in a line similar to `127.0.0.1 project_x.local`. This will tell your browser when you type in `project_x.local` to go to the IP `127.0.0.1` (localhost). Your apache Vhost will then redirect to your project_x directory at `C://xampp/htdocs/project_x`.

Hope this all makes sense and works for you!

Comment: You will just need to look for the Apache files on the Z: drive instead of C: and same with referencing where the project is stored on the Z: drive. The hosts file wants to stay on the same drive as your OS and in the same location as where it was found.

Comment: It was the Z: drive where I edited the apache files, so therefore I dont know why it wont direct

Comment: I believe the problem being that I have 2 Xampps installed but I dont know how to resolve this without removing one of them